# Components.classes[this.cid] is undefined

Tags: javascript

При открытии фаерфокс вот такое происходит. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте отключать расширения поочередно. [Источник](http://forum.mozilla-russia.org/viewtopic.php?id=46038)
Если это не помогло, то возможно Ваш антивирус имеет средства контроля ссылок на странице, отключите опцию в настройках антивируса.